# Run Beyond Compare4 Script from Java?

Tags: java, process, beyondcompare4

Beyond compare provides a script to get the Report in a html format.
I want to run the script through java to get the report in a particular folder 
but i am getting error everytime.

MyScript

```
 text-report layout:Interleived &
 options:ignore-unimportant,display-context &
 output-to:%3 output-options:html-color %1 %2
```

My java call to the script

```
    String left = "D:\\DatabaseModifier\\VIS VS EBZVIS\\VIS_Lookup_left.xls";
    String right = "D:\\DatabaseModifier\\VIS VS EBZVIS\\EBZVIS_Lookup_right.xls";

try{
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare4\\BCompare", "@D:\\DatabaseModifier\\MyScript.txt",left,right,"D:\\DatabaseModifier\\check.html").start();

   }catch(Exception e){

   }
```

Earlier there was no check.html i created the file still getting the same error

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and hit and trail this is the script

```
data-report layout:Interleaved options:ignore-unimportant output-to:"%3" output-options:html-color "%1" "%2"
```

and the java call

```
String left = "D:\\DatabaseModifier\\VIS VS EBZVIS\\VIS_Lookup_left.xls";
String right = "D:\\DatabaseModifier\\VIS VS EBZVIS\\EBZVIS_Lookup_right.xls";


   try{
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BCompare", "@D:\\DatabaseModifier\\MyScript.txt",left,right,"D:\\DatabaseModifier\\check.html").start();

   }catch(Exception e){

   }
```